# bootstrap grid system filling image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a column that is separated into 2 nested columns. They both should be images that cover the entire height and width of their respected columns. However, for some reason the images go over the div that contains them.

```
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
        <img class="fitimages" src="./images/pic1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
        <img class="fitimages" src="./images/pic2.jpg">
    </div>
```

```
 .fitimages{
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
```

}

I used max-width and max-height so that they would surround the parent div but for some reason the left image doesn't fill the entire width and height while the right one goes over it.

Answer (score 0):

give your img this style : `object-fit: cover;`